# How to check a column to see if the first value of a string is a number in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with a column inside a pyspark dataframe that is of string type, and im trying to isolate string values that start with a number and then convert that column to a new string based on that condition.

How can I apply something to a whole column to check to see if the first value is a string?

Comment: Lucas, ask a full question, backed with data sample and desired results

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you asking for something like this?

```
newdf = (
DF.withColumn('is_start_with_digit', df.MyColumn.substr(1, 1).cast("int").isNotNull())

)
```